# Laravel Spark / Vue.js - Bus.$emit to parent component?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

I have a 'dashboard' component that houses a 'modal' and 'header'.

My modal Vue component has an 'updateTeam' method:

```
updateTeam: function() {

   Spark.put(`/settings/${Spark.pluralTeamString}/${this.team.id}/name`, this.form)
       .then(() => {
           Bus.$emit('updateTeamData');
       });
}
```

What I want is for the data that is passed into my 'header component' to update.

My attempt currently is in my main 'dashboard' component I have:

```
// methods()
getTeam() {
    axios.get(`/${Spark.pluralTeamString}/${this.team.id}`)
        .then(response => {
            this.team = response.data;
        });
}

// mounted()
Bus.$on('updateTeamData', function () {
    $this.getTeam();
});
```

I the Bus.$emit would be able to trigger the method in the parent component, which would then update the prop that Is passed to the header component. Nothing happens as of the current code.

Header component is used in the template tag of dashboard component:

```
<team-admin-header :team="team"></team-admin-header>
```

Comment: Is `$this` set to `this` somewhere? Did you mean to pass the `team` in the event? Does `getTeam` get called?

Comment: @BertEvans Yeah $this is preset elsewhere. getTeam doesn't get called unless its in the modal component.

Comment: What I mean is, when the modal $emits, is `getTeam` getting called? And is the team property updated? It could be everything is working and you just dont see the update because of how the header handles the property.

Comment: @BertEvans Nope, a console log inside the getTeam method doesn't get called. The header also outputs the team.name so I should also see that change.

Comment: @BertEvans Actually somehow got it working now. Warning thrown about editing a prop but I can handle that. Thanks!

Comment: No worries :) Glad it's working.